# Tomcat Apache 6 server on Eclipse Error

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, tomcat6

Not able to add Apache tomcat  6.0 server in eclipse.

FYI
I have my eclipse-standard-kepler-SR2-win32 this contains J2EE package.
And the environment variables needed for java are already set up.Incase i need to modify anything for apache tomcat server please list in the steps.

I have downlaoded tomcat from http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi In this in the end Source Code Distributions downlaoded the zip from there and extracted it on desktop.

I am getting this error  `The Tomcat installation directory is not valid. It is missing expected file or folder lib/jasper-el.jar.`

Please help me with steps.I have tried searching the same but nothing was clear and to the point.

Going to `Windows>Perferrence>server>Runtime Environment>Add and then i am selecting the directory in which my apache bin folder is there.`

Please provide the clear and specific steps.

Answer (score 0):

Just check your apache lib folder for this file is available. if not then download and present it.

Comment: this could just be a comment . i hope it wouldnt be a complete answer

Comment: Well, first of all i look for comment, but unfortunately i am not able to comment so, i have made this as answer i am sure this is the solution for this problem probably if everything is fine.

Comment: Yeah Manish i just figured that the lib folder is missing.Would anyone let me know some other site from where i can download the complete package with the lib folder?

Comment: actually your zip folder if not properly unzip due to that you do not have lib folder. Plz download apache tomacat from http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi and double click on file after download. if it is open in window like in case of winrar without error then download is complete other wise you have to download it again. some time file not download completely. unzip properly then you will find it. as other source can be harmful for the system so, i don't suggest any website except apache.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select HOME directory of your tomcat.. like D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.42.. Try this and tell us check [this](http://www.jpgtutorials.com/installing-and-configuring-eclipse-with-tomcat-in-windows) link for installation of tomcat in windows

Comment: The problem is there are
http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi

In this there is binary distribution and Source code distribution.
I am downloading the zip from source code distrubition.And it does not contain the lib folder which is supposed to have that jasper-el.jar>>>
And the other links above are blocked here.So any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting incorrect directory. Instead of apache/bin, select apache home directory while configuring the server.

Comment: Excuse me.I have written i have selcted the directory in which bin is present.
That means C:\Users\465146\Desktop\apache-tomcat-6.0.39-src\apache-tomcat-6.0.39-src
After this the bin folder will come.And the first apache is one folder inside that my apache is present.